# nginx upstream not working

Tags: nginx, iis, reverse-proxy, proxypass

`upstream` does not work when the proxyed server has **more than one host name binding** on the **same port**.

I ran into this issue while trying to configure *nginx (1.9.12-1~trusty)* to `proxy_pass` a *Windows Server 2012* host.

I have reproduced the same behavior on my own *Windows 10* machine.

In the below configuration all host names point to the same machine IP.

**Requests work sometimes**

Note: I exepect this is when `localhost:7778` is choosen to be proxyed.

```
http {
    upstream w {
        server test1:80;
        server test2:80;
        server localhost:7778;
    }

    server {
        listen       8001;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://w;
        }
    }
}
```

**Requests work none of the time**

Note: edited as pointed out by Alexey.

```
http {
    upstream w {
        server test1:80;
        server test2:80;
        # server localhost:7778;
    }

    server {
        listen       8001;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://w;
        }
    }
}
```

**Requests work all the time**

```
http {

    server {
        listen       8001;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://test1:80;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
http {

    server {
        listen       8001;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://test2:80;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
http {

    server {
        listen       8001;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:7778;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Second example misses `http://` in `proxy_pass`. Too bad that your upstreams require different hostnames. You should configure them to use the same name and use that name in `proxy_set_header Host ....`

Comment: proxy_set_header Host is the answer, do you want to add an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `proxy_pass` without [`proxy_set_header`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_set_header) directives, nginx will use some default headers. Most times it's what you would want or, at least, harmless, but in your case you have to set them manually.

When you write `proxy_pass http://w`, nginx will set `proxy_set_header Host w`. If you need another `Host` header, you should set it explicitly. Most common is to use `proxy_set_header Host $host` (or `proxy_set_header Host $http_host`).

So this should work for you:

```
upstream w {
    server test1:80;
    server test2:80;
    server localhost:7778;
}

server {
    listen       8001;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://w;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting, that setting the host explicitly (rather than using $host) can help when testing (getting familiar with) this behavior.